Firewall not reverse translating NAT address in VyOS GNS3
I'm using two VyOS images as Firewalls in gns3, to which I have connected two routers, one from an inside network and another from an outside network. I configured NAT in both  for the internal network 10.0.0.0/8 as follows:
 $ configure
 # set nat source rule 10 outbound-interface eth0
 # set nat source rule 10 source address 10.0.0.0/8
 # set nat source rule 10 translation address 192.1.0.1-192.1.0.10
 # commit
 # exit

When I try to ping from a PC1 in the internal network to a PC2 in the external network, I can detect the packet going with the correct translation done, but when it comes back, my FW where the packet passes through doesn't know how to handle it. The FW also has a default route set as set protocols static route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 200.1.1.10, in which 200.1.1.10 is the gate to the external network.
As the FW doesn't have the net 192.1.0.0 in the IP route table, I think it might be just throwing it back to the default route. But if it has the NAT configured, shouldn't it be able to translate and find the correct destination (It has the internal network in the IP route table).
Thank you.
